# Hidden folder showing ~lock file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am just preparing a doc file. i am using LibreOffice in ubuntu.
The name of the file is

> WebApplicationRequirements.doc

When i am saving that in a drive, an extra file  shows in the hidden file.
The name is

> .~lock.WebApplicationRequirements.doc#

When i am pushing that in a remote repository it is including that hidden  file. If i delete that fill will it harm the original file. And why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, that hidden file is a lock file used internally by LibreOffice. To prevent multiple LibreOffice application instances from writing to the same file at the same time. It's not generally harmful to delete that file. It should get re-created again next time you open that file again in LibreOffice.

You haven't indicated what remote repo system you are using. But also note that most repro systems (e.g. git) have the concept of ignore files which allow you to configure which files to ignore during commit. If your repro system has that you probably want to add a rule to ignore the lock files so that they are not committed/pushed.